# Android ITelephony class context

Tags: android, telephony, android-source, telephonymanager

I am currently digging around in the Android source code, in order to understand the different telephony related packages and containing classes. One class I have a problem understanding is the `ITelephony` interface class. I understand that it is an [AIDL](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html) interface, which are used for IPC between different Android processes (each application runs under their own PID.) I also understand that it is called frequently by the [`TelephonyManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) class, to provide the actual implementation of the public telephony SDK.

- **Which classes are actually implementing 
  this interface and responding to the IPC calls?**
- What is the larger context the ITelephony interface is used in?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> - Which classes are actually
>     implementing this interface and
>     responding to the IPC calls?

[PhoneInterfaceManager](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/packages/apps/Phone/src/com/android/phone/PhoneInterfaceManager.java) implements the ITelephony interface. The ITelephony interface provides access to the TAPI layer. However you are only supposed to use the TelephonyManager to access Telephony events and stuff.

Comment: Hi. I am porting android, so I have to provide the actual implementation for the ITelephony interface. :) Do you have additional details on where and why the IPC is performed? Is the PhoneInterfaceManager always running under another process, and calls to this through the ITelephony interface automatically synchronised over IPC?

Comment: What are this TAPI layer you are talking about, I only find the stuff in com.android.internal.telephony.Phone and friends, there is no "real" telephony API, right?

Comment: I'll answer all your questions in a bit. I got some stuff to do now. and yes i didn't mean actual TAPI, my bad i'll edit it later.